# code or pre element isn't working perfectly on Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a landing page for myself with Twitter Bootstrap framework and I want to show some code on my landing page and that's why I am writing my code into `<code></code>` or `<pr></pre>` this elements but it's not showing. I put my code like below:

```
<code>
<command type="?">Click Me!</command>
</code>
```

or

```
<pre>
<command type="?">Click Me!</command>
</pre>
```

But, Twitter Bootstrap is only showing to me "Click Me!" word. He don't show me the whole code into the `<code>` or `<pre>` elements.

How may I fix this?

Comment: what's `<command type="?">`?

Comment: Hi @ashley,
Thanks to you for at-least answer me. It's nothing actually. It's just a demo I wrote. Actually, the code isn't showing on the Code or Pre elements. I don't know why :(

If I write List items on the Pre or Code elements then it's not showing the whole List items code. It's just showing the list items. But, I want to show the whole code what I wrote on the Code or Pre element. That's the thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to replace the `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively, or they will be interpreted as HTML:

```
<pre>
&lt;command type="?"&gt; Click Me! &lt;/command&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: Wow @Andy, It's working perfectly now :) I understood now everything! Thank you!

Comment: Great, please mark this answer as Accepted, so that others can benefit.

Comment: Anywhere in an HTML document that you want the user to actually *see* the < or >, you replace it with `&lt;` or `&gt;`.  That goes for the opening and closing tags.